# ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 30.0 (TID 28) java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: pyspark

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Project\Airline_Migration_System\bronze.py", line 140, in 
update_df_by_anlytic.write.parquet(anlytic_path,mode="overwrite")
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 1721, in parquet
self._jwrite.parquet(path)
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in **call**
return_value = get_return_value(
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 179, in deco
return f(*a, **kw)
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o155.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 30.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 30.0 (TID 28) (DESKTOP-VSHANKAR98 executor driver): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
File file:/F:/Project/proceed_data/bronze/airport/good_data/analytic_way/part-00000-e7abe36d-83dd-49c8-85a4-a89b7590660d-c000.snappy.parquet does not exist

It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate
the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by
recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.

```
at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.readCurrentFileNotFoundError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:661)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceScanExec.scala:561)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
File file:/F:/Project/proceed_data/bronze/airport/good_data/analytic_way/part-00000-e7abe36d-83dd-49c8-85a4-a89b7590660d-c000.snappy.parquet does not exist

It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate
the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by
recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.

```
at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.readCurrentFileNotFoundError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:661)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceScanExec.scala:561)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: Where's your source code?